# Debugging multiple SSL streams in java, how to tell them apart

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

I've enabled SSL debugging to troubleshoot a problem mutual authentication and running into a
challange.  When a single SSL connection is made it's clear that all of the log messages are
associated with single TLS connection.

However, when multiple TLS connections are being made, I'm finding it difficult to identify what TLS
logs belong to what TLS connections.  I'm using Java 8 or Java 11 depending on the environment.
For this question, I'll stick to the format in the Java11 environment.

**Is there anything in the SSL debug log line that uniquely identifies a given SSL connection?  If so what is it?**

I think it's likely the 3rd or 4th field in a log message.  For example, the following are logs that
match the string **https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1** in some multi-threaded debugging I've done each
thread has a uniq ID so this (exec-1) might represent a given thread.

```
grep https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1 log-for-so-2023-03-24T181816Z.log
javax.net.ssl|ALL|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.150 UTC|HandshakeContext.java:347|Ignore unsupported cipher suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.184 UTC|ClientHello.java:798|Consuming ClientHello handshake message (
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.215 UTC|ServerHello.java:364|Produced ServerHello handshake message (
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.219 UTC|CertificateMessage.java:271|Produced server Certificate handshake message (
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.253 UTC|ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:491|Produced ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message (
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.265 UTC|CertificateRequest.java:630|Produced CertificateRequest handshake message (
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.265 UTC|ServerHelloDone.java:97|Produced ServerHelloDone handshake message (
```

But when I'm on debugging on a server that has multiple TLS connections being made, I'm not seeing
any clear pattern.

#### Examining the 4th field, https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1

In one case, the https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1 is being used for different connections.  I can tell
that because the **Consuming server Certificate handshake** lists the server certificate to which a
connection is made.  It is, however, possible that this string is a "thread" (from a thread pool)
and the thread is being re-used to handle another SSL request.

#### Examining the pattern of logs

Below is a list of the unique first four fields, so all javax.net.ssl log lines begin with one of
these patterns.

```
grep '^javax.net.ssl' log-for-so-2023-03-24T181816Z.log | awk -F'|' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' | sort -u
javax.net.ssl ALL 51 https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1
javax.net.ssl DEBUG 01 main
javax.net.ssl DEBUG 03 Finalizer
javax.net.ssl DEBUG 51 https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1
javax.net.ssl DEBUG 52 https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-2
javax.net.ssl DEBUG 56 https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-6
javax.net.ssl WARNING 51 https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1
javax.net.ssl WARNING 56 https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-6
```

#### Examining the 3rd field.  Based on studying the logs, I know that the

string **https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1** has logs for handling the TLS connection I've made for this
so question.

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.184 UTC|ClientHello.java:798|Consuming ClientHello handshake message (
```

So I greped for '|51|' to see that number is unique, but again it is used for different connections.

```
grep '^javax.net.ssl' log-for-so-2023-03-24T181816Z.log | grep '|51|'  | less
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.169 UTC|SSLExtensions.java:135|Ignore unknown or unsupported extension (
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.180 UTC|SignatureScheme.java:295|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.180 UTC|SignatureScheme.java:295|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|51|https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1|2023-03-24 18:22:22.184 UTC|ClientHello.java:798|Consuming ClientHello handshake message (
```

In this simplistic single TLS connection case the id `51` only appears with the
thread **https-jsse-nio-8005-exec-1** but in the server mutli-TLS connection case, I see this number
used on different TLS connections.

**Is there a way to associated the SSL DEBUG logs with a SSL/TLS connection?**

### Looking for a solution

I searched for how to configure the log output in hopes it might document these fields but so far haven't found that answer.

Comment: See ["Debug Output Format" in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-4D421910-C36D-40A2-8BA2-7D42CCBED3C6). Fields 3 and 4 both identify the thread and will be tied to each other as long as the thread exists, which in webservers is often as long as the server is running. In a server using SSLSocket a given thread can do only one handshake at a time, but with SSLEngine it can do more than one; usually different threads will not be involved in a single connection but will do different connections.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, I created an answer based on your comment.  I don't know if it's possible to chown and answer from me to you, but feel free to copy my answer and create a new answer (owned by you) so I can select it as the answer.  (then I'll delete this comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is credited to  @dave_thompson_085.

> Is there anything in the SSL debug log line that uniquely identifies a given SSL connection? If so what is it?

Fields 3 and 4 both identify the thread and will be tied to each other as long as the thread exists, which in webservers is often as long as the server is running. In a server using SSLSocket a given thread can do only one handshake at a time, but with SSLEngine it can do more than one; usually different threads will not be involved in a single connection but will do different connections.

See [Java 11 Debugging TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-4D421910-C36D-40A2-8BA2-7D42CCBED3C6) link (credit to @dave_thompson_085) which says:

**Debug Output Format**

> Each line of the debug output contains the following information; each field is separated by a vertical bar (|):
>
> Logger name (System.getLogger("javax.net.ssl"))
> Debug level (System.Logger.Level)
> Thread ID (Thread.currentThread().getId())
> Thread name (Thread.currentThread().getName())
> Date and time
> Caller (location of the logging call)
> Message

The link's page also provides a wealth of other information about debugging TLS in Java.